# Box2D Contact Listener Collision Only Works Intermittently

Tags: c++, collision-detection, box2d

I have a dynamic body colliding with a dynamic body and a simple contact listener class shown below:

```
void myContactListener::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
{
    void* bodyUserData = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody()->GetUserData();

    if (bodyUserData)
    {
        static_cast<EnemyEntity*>(bodyUserData)->startContact();
    }

    bodyUserData = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody()->GetUserData();

    if (bodyUserData)
    {
        static_cast<EnemyEntity*>(bodyUserData)->endContact();
    }
}

void myContactListener::EndContact(b2Contact* contact)
{
    void* bodyUserData = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody()->GetUserData();

    if (bodyUserData)
        static_cast<EnemyEntity*>(bodyUserData)->endContact();

    bodyUserData = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody()->GetUserData();

    if (bodyUserData)
        static_cast<EnemyEntity*>(bodyUserData)->endContact();
}
```

Whenever I move either of the dynamic bodies into each other, a collision is always detected the first time as well as a stop of collision. However, if I try to collide them once again, it often doesn't detect any collision after the first time. It does sometimes though. What can I do to fix this? Nothing else in my code touches any Box2D code.

Here is my contact listener header file:

```
class myContactListener : public b2ContactListener
{
private:
public:
    // Contact listener methods
    void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact);
    void EndContact(b2Contact* contact);
};
```

And the EnemyEntity Box2D method:

```
void EnemyEntity::createStarBox2DCollision(b2World *world)
{
    enemyType = EnemyType::Star;

    def.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    def.position.Set(1000, 1000);
    body = world->CreateBody(&def);
    box.SetAsBox(rectShapeSize.x / 2, rectShapeSize.y / 2);

    fixtureDef.shape = &box;
    fixtureDef.density = 1.0;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.3;

    body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
    body->SetUserData(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should have

```
void myContactListener::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
{
    ...
        static_cast<EnemyEntity*>(bodyUserData)->startContact();
    }
}
```

rather than

```
void myContactListener::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
{
    ...
    static_cast<EnemyEntity*>(bodyUserData)->endContact();
    }
}
```

for both bodies, rather than only for A

Comment: Thank you for that but unfortunately that did not fix the problem.